# Получить вес изображения <img> [jQuery / JS]

Tags: jquery, img, filesize

Нужно узнать вес изображения отображаемого на странице в теге `<img>`
Все доступно в консоли, но как вытащить в переменную??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD: вес изображения (Кб) = file size**

Comment: "вес изображения" - ??

Comment: @Igor вес изображения в Килобайтах, он же file size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получите размер изображения в байтах:

```js
function GetImageSizeInBytes(imgURL) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('HEAD', imgURL, false);
  request.send(null);
  var headerText = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
  var re = /Content\-Length\s*:\s*(\d+)/i;
  re.exec(headerText);

  return parseInt(RegExp.$1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего обратиться к свойству изображения. У него есть значение
img.target.files.size, в котором он показан в браузере в байтах. Соответственно, можно там и посмотреть.
Если нужна функция, которая будет за этим наблюдать, то выглядит она примерно так:

```js
const imgSize = (image) => {
  console.log(image.target.files.size)
}
```

Comment: Это для изображений загруженных с помощью input.file,
Однако есть ли способ определить вес у обычного изображения на странице <img>?